# Multiple databases with shared data

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a customer database.  In this database is a table that holds the product licenses that the user has purchased.  The primary key is UserLicenseId.

In the products themselves, we use the UserLicenseId to identify information with the purchase.  For example, if they save a note in the product: UserLicenseId, Note, DateWritten.

Are they any best practices to make sure that the backups and restores of the separate databases keep the UserLicenseId fields in synch?

Comment: This question should be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JorgeCampos, not sure. As I know, there is not admin solution to solve this problem.  I think, the solution should be in the development field. For example, keep data together or create special sync mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the licenses data from Licenses database to Product database periodically. And create foreign key on the database level. I think - it is a best solution.

But if you don't agree, here is some thoughts:

- You must backup the database with Licenses first, to guarantee, that you don't have licenses in the Products database, which don't exist in the Licenses.
- How do you keep this field in sync right now ? Do you have any database constraints which can keep them in sync ?  I think, you don't have. So, we should not to expect this behavior from backup operation.  May it will be better to create the procedure, which will be check the consistency of data between two databases and put the launch of this procedure in the restore regulations.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the two databases is to be regarded as a set that must be in sync, and you don't want to rely on database backups not being in synch -

I would recommend an external backup of the data, outside of the backup of the database as a whole.

You could BCP data out of those tables into a set of files and check these into a version control system, or zip them together in a file who's name includes the as of date.